# The definition of this 1-form $\gamma$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms, principal-bundles

Let $M$ be a manifold on which acts a Lie group $G$.

> Let $\sigma \in \mathcal{A}^1(M) \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ be a connection form for the principal bundle $M \rightarrow M/G$. We define a $G$- invariant 1-form $\gamma$ on $M × \mathfrak{g}^*$ in the following way
> $$(m,\xi) \in M × \mathfrak{g}^*, \gamma_{|(m,\xi)}:= \langle \sigma_{|m}, \xi\rangle.$$

I don't understand the definition of the 1-form $\gamma$: suppose we choose a tangent vector $X \in T_{(m,\xi)}(M × \mathfrak{g}^*)$, then what is $\gamma_{|(m,\xi)}(X)$ ?

Comment: They are using $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to denote the pairing of $\mathfrak g^*$ and $\mathfrak g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words, $\gamma$ is a $1$-form on $M\times \mathfrak{g}^*$ that works like this: $\gamma$ takes $(m,\xi)$ to a linear functional $\gamma_{(m,\xi)}: T_mM\times \mathfrak{g}^* \to \Bbb R$, and $\gamma_{(m,\xi)}$ takes $(v,\eta)\in T_mM\times \mathfrak{g}^*$ to the value of $\xi\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ evaluated at $\sigma_m(v)$. But the quantity $\xi(\sigma_m(v))$ is being denoted as $\langle \sigma_m(v),\xi\rangle$ (in context, $\langle \xi, \sigma_m(v)\rangle$ would also be acceptable).

This $\gamma$ is essentially a tautological form built from $\sigma$.

Comment: Why is the element $\eta$  not used in definition ?

Comment: Here's the reasoning: you really care about the quantity $\sigma_m(v) \in \mathfrak{g}$ (where $m\in M$ and $v \in T_mM$). Knowing it is the same as knowing $\xi(\sigma_m(v))$ for all $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}^*$. To see this as the value of a $1$-form, the point argument must be $(m,\xi)$ instead of merely $\xi$. So if this is a $1$-form on $M \times \mathfrak{g}^*$, something tangent to $\mathfrak{g}^*$ (our $\eta$) must be part of the vector argument, but this won't give us any new information about the quantities $\xi(\sigma_m(v))$ we care about.

Comment: If $X = (v,\eta)$, then $v$ is what you obtain after pushing $X$ forward with the derivative of the projection $M\times \mathfrak{g}^* \to M$. You can write $$\gamma_{(m,\xi)}(X) = \langle \xi, \sigma_m ({\rm d}\pi_{(m,\xi)}(X))\rangle.$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivo Terek for your explanation!